# Invalid state url within $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to run the app due to error "Error: Duplicate parameter name 'id' in pattern '/instance/:id/instance/:id/edit'"

JS

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url : '/home',
        templateUrl : 'home-view.html',
        controller : 'homeController'
    })
    .state('instance', {
        url : '/instance/:id',
        templateUrl : 'data-view.html',
        controller : 'instanceController'
    })
    .state('instance.edit', {
        url: '/instance/:id/edit', 
        templateUrl : 'edit-table.html',
        controller : 'instanceEditController'
    });

});

routerApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$state', function($state, $scope) {
  console.log("inside home controller");
}]);

routerApp.controller('instanceController', ['$scope', '$state', function($state, $scope) {
  console.log("inside instance view controller");
  $scope.data = [
   {
     "Name" : "Hello"
   }  
  ]
}]);

routerApp.controller('instanceEditController', ['$scope', '$state', function($state, $scope) {
   console.log("inside instance edit controller");

}]);
```

How can I pass data between the states ? I'm currently using

```
<a ui-sref=".edit{{'id' : 2, 'data' : data}}" class="btn btn-primary">Instance View</a>
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/IMOYLn8dFzGM4p9OB7My?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit confused about the nested states of AngularJS ui-router.

I fixed some issues of your plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YF6ePE1ALdp7qsBaK6oD?p=preview
(There are other issues, but it gives you a good start).

Basically, you don't need to replicate the whole URL when you have a nested state, ie:

**From:**

```
.state('instance.edit', {
  url: '/instance/:id/edit', 
  templateUrl : 'edit-table.html',
  controller : 'instanceEditController'
});
```

**Change to:**

```
.state('instance.edit', {
  url: '/edit', 
  templateUrl : 'edit-table.html',
  controller : 'instanceEditController'
});
```

For nested states, I suggest this documentation: [Nested States & Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

The other question, how to pass data, you are almost there:

```
ui-sref="instance({id:2})
```

Take a look at this demo here: [UI-Router Demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/), it contains a good example of what you are trying to accomplish.

And again, the `ui-router` wiki is a good read: [angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)